# How to execute the complete java class from a JButton not only a function()?

Tags: java, class, jakarta-ee, applet, jbutton

like by using:

```
b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        new sign_in();
    }
});
```

If the function's name `is sign_in()` we can use above for JButton b3 but
if i want to execute the class `sign_in{}`  or the `main()` function what should i change in the action performed??

Comment: In java you can't execute a class. You can execute methods in a class.

Comment: to execute the static `main` method of class `SignIn` use the statement `SignIn.main()` (eventually adding arguments)

Comment: @Mustafa please review your edit, "is" is not part of the function name